# do DIVs inside form tags cause problems?

Tags: forms, html

It seems sometime to work fine and sometimes not, so in should I use divs inside form or not?
and in general is there a guide for what HTML tags will not work inside other tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divs do not cause any intrinsic problems inside forms. Any CSS rules or JS that might get applied to them may cause problems, but the same is true of any element.

The [HTML 4.01 specification](http://w3.org/TR/html4/) includes [a guide on how to read DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3). This is applicable for HTML 3.2 and 4.x as well as XHTML 1.x. HTML 5 does not have an official DTD, so you have to pay attention to the "Content model" for each element in the [spec](http://w3.org/TR/html5/).

Comment: So this means I can put any tag inside any other without the HTML messing up?

Comment: No. The DTDs describe which elements are allowed inside which other elements.